# CSS is not loading on staging server

Tags: config, url, multi-environment

I'm quite new to server config, so this might be a simple mistake. I have a local environment setup on my computer that works just fine. I uploaded my project to my staging server at AWS and the only thing that loads is the index.html in my `craft` folder. For some reason it gives me a `"The requested URL /css/bootstrap.min.css was not found on this server"` error for every folder or file I have inside of public folder.

```php
<?php

/**
* General Configuration
*
* All of your system's general configuration settings go in here.
* You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php
*/

return array(
);
```

My craft folder in my staging is at: `/var/www/craft-portfolio/`

My Public folder is at: `/var/www/craft-portfolio`

The web root is the public folder that is `/var/www/craft-portfolio/public`

Comment: Where is the craft folder located in relation to web root? Can you post your general.php file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set the URLs to your files. I don't know if I got your folder structure right. But let's suppose that your web root is set to
`/var/www/craft-portfolio/public/`,

your CSS folder is
`/var/www/craft-portfolio/public/css/`

and your Craft folder (actually not relevant) is
`/var/www/craft-portfolio/craft/`.

**Root-relative URL**

Root-relative URLs start with a `/` character.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/build.css" />
```

If you are using multiple environments, the path from the web root to your file has to be the same on each environment.
Something like this won't work with root-relative URLs:

```
http://mysite.com/css/build.css
http://192.168.178.20/projects/mysite/css/build.css
```

**Absolute URL**

Add the complete URL of the CSS file to the link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/css/build.css" />
```

You can also use Craft's global [`siteUrl`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#siteUrl) variable. To do that define the site's URL (`http://mysite.com/`) in Settings → General in the Control Panel and add the variable to your tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ siteUrl }}css/build.css" />
```

If you want to use the variable in a multi-environment setup, define it in your `general.php` file (this overrides the CP settings):

```
return array(

    '192.168.178.20' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://192.168.178.20/projects/mysite/',
    ),

    'craft.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://craft.dev/',
    ),

    'mysite.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://mysite.com/',
    )
);
```

Just be careful if you want to use this on a multilingual Craft site. If you have multiple locales configured, `siteUrl` will be set to each locale's site URL, which might point to different folders.
You can avoid this by setting a [custom variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables) (eg. `baseUrl`) in your `general.php` file:

```
'environmentVariables' => array(
    'baseUrl'  => 'http://example.dev/',
)
```

and then use the absolute URL like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ craft.config.environmentVariables.baseUrl }}css/build.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that your path to resources are relative to your

```
index.php
```

Whether that's `./public/index.php` or `./index.php` where craft is in the same directory level as `index.php` make sure that's consistent at all three locations.